# Problem with a sql statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
string insertCommand = 
    "INSERT INTO Users (UserID) VALUES" + "" + "(CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '" + 
    UsersIdentityToinsert + "'),'"+ userName+",0,null')";
```

it tells me:

> ```
> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
> ```
>
> in the VALUES clause. The number of
>   values in the VALUES clause must match
>   the number of columns specified in the
>   INSERT statement.

But i have four columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only have UserID in the insert list but in the value list, you have two values -  a uniqueidentifier and a username

this would work better: (assuming the name of your username column)

```
string insertCommand = 
    "INSERT INTO Users (UserID, username) VALUES" + "" + 
    "(CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '" + UsersIdentityToinsert + "'),'"+ userName+"')";
```

EDIT:

I feel i need to address this part a bit more clearly:

> But i have four columns?

The error you received refers to the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement - not the actual table so if you start an INSERT with:

```
INSERT INTO AnyTable (ColumnA, ColumnB)
```

you need to match the number of columns here in your VALUES clause

```
VALUES ("Value1", "Value2")
```

Comment: it would work even better if we were using parameters so we could guard against sql injection and ugly code. :)

Comment: hmmm. are u saying that i need to Declare @Username , UniqueIdentifier..and then SET them tothe values....would that prevent the sql attack?

Comment: the sql injection is a valid point but more than just declare them - you should validate any values that you get as well

Comment: WOW, it seems to require more than one sql statement , huh

Comment: potentially, yes. but imagine if someone were to sign up with the username: `usr');drop database aaa;`. you need to make sure that no one can do that. (please note, i don't really know if that would work but it serves as an extreme example)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "UserName" in column Names, that is, Column Name and values mismathch.

```
string insertCommand = 
    "INSERT INTO Users (UserID,UserName) VALUES" + "" + 
    "(CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, '" + UsersIdentityToinsert + "'),'"+ userName+"')";
```